# How to extend a class that extends App

Tags: scala

I have a main base class and I want to extend it so that the main class provides basic functions to the extended class:

```
class Foo extends App {
  println("Foo")
  def bar = {}
}

class Foo2 extends Foo {
  println("Foo2")
}

object Foo2 extends Foo2 {

}
```

But this does not work. The compile complains `warning: Foo2 has a main method with parameter type Array[String], but Foo2 will not be a runnable program.
  Reason: companion contains its own main method, which means no static forwarder can be generated.`

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an ambiguous name in your code. Just rename the class or object and you'll be fine

```
class Foo extends App {
  println("Foo")
  def bar = {}
}

class FooX extends Foo {
  println("Foo2")
}

object Foo2 extends FooX {

}
```

Comment: This does not seem to print anything

Comment: How do you run it? In IntelliJ I just run the object Foo2 and it prints first "Foo" followed by "Foo2" as expected